# Why does this code results in Stack Overflow c#?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

The code below throws stack overflow. DoSomething in B calls DoSomething in A. DoSomething in A is supposed to call its X's implementation of method but it calls DoSomething of its derived class B. Why? is this a bug?

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            B b = new B();
            b.DoSomething();
        }
    }
    interface X
    {
        void DoSomething();
    }
    class A : X
    {
        protected void DoSomething() => ((X)this).DoSomething(); // Making visible to derived classes
        void X.DoSomething() => Console.ReadKey();
    }
    interface Y : X
    {
        void DoSomethingElse();
    }
    class B : A, Y
    {
        public new void DoSomething() => base.DoSomething(); //Making publically visible
        public void DoSomethingElse() { }
    }
}
```

BTW this code works fine (if I do not inherit X in Y):

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            B b = new B();
            b.DoSomething();
        }
    }
    interface X
    {
        void DoSomething();
    }
    class A : X
    {
        protected void DoSomething() => ((X)this).DoSomething(); // Making visible to derived classes
        void X.DoSomething() => Console.ReadKey();
    }
    interface Y
    {
        void DoSomethingElse();
    }
    class B : A, Y
    {
        public new void DoSomething() => base.DoSomething(); //Making publically visible
        public void DoSomethingElse() { }
    }
}
```

Why in first example, DoSomething in B is trying to implement X's DoSomething method which has already been implemented by A. If its not bug, how can I stop class B from doing so without modifying Y interface. Since I want to reflect in Y that it inherits X.

Comment: The StackOverflow error refrest to the callstack. Basically you got recursion in your code. And hte recurions is either infinite, or so close as to trip up the infinite detection. But I can not tell where it is, because you threw way to much code and inheritance into our faces. Please provide a Minimal example for this problem.

Comment: The naming convention for Interfacs is also to append a i to the front of their name. That way we can tell that `class B : A, iY` is *not* a totally invalid atempt at multiple inheritance at a glance. Rather then having to figure out your custom naming sheme.

Comment: Solution:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6153f30c-2ab3-4867-86a1-a07e754a0cec/why-does-this-code-results-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens, because your calls invoke each other, this `public new void DoSomething() => base.DoSomething();` is calling base method, which is `protected void DoSomething() => ((X)this).DoSomething();`

`this` instance is casted to `X` type, which is implemented by `A` and `B` obviously, `((X)this).DoSomething();` calls `DoSomething()` from `B` class and you are getting an infinite recursion.

The reason of this behavior is that when an interface is explicitly implemented more than once in the type hierarchy, the implementation in the most-derived type is used. You can have a look at [language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces#interface-mapping) for details.

You can avoid it by making `DoSomething()` method `public` in class `A` and remove its declaration in `B`, like that

```cs
class A : X
{
    public void DoSomething() => ((X)this).DoSomething(); // Making visible to derived classes
    void X.DoSomething() => Console.ReadKey();
}
interface Y : X
{
    void DoSomethingElse();
}
class B : A, Y
{
    public void DoSomethingElse() { }
}
```

Comment: I am casting this to X. X's DoSomething is implemented in A, why its calling DoSomething of B?

Comment: @ZDSAlpha Because that is what `this.DoSomething()` does.

Comment: How can I make it call X.DoSomething implemented in A?

Comment: You've already found a solution, remove `X` inheritance in `Y` interface

Comment: Can I stop B from implementing method X.DoSomething without changing method name??

Comment: @ZDSAlpha You can make `DoSomething()` in `A` public and remove its declaration in `B`, I'll update an answer

Comment: There is a solution by moving the implementation from X.DoSomething() to A.DoSomething(). Here is the answer:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6153f30c-2ab3-4867-86a1-a07e754a0cec/why-does-this-code-results-in-stack-overflow